# How many bytes is a GB of GPU memory?

Tags: memory, gpu, byte

NVIDIA specifies that their [GeForce RTX 3090 (Ti)](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/30-series/rtx-3090-3090ti/) has 24 GB of memory. How are you supposed to know how much data you can fit on it, when some sources use 1 GB = 1,024<sup>3</sup> bytes, while other sources use 1 GB = 1,000<sup>3</sup> bytes? Can you assume that hardware manufacturers always use 1,000-base since that means they can write higher number in the specifications, or do some hardware manufacturers still use 1,024-base?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect 1 GB = 1,024^3 as I only encountered 1 GB = 1,000^3 in the context of storage as in SSD.